# Eloquent updates all rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Basically, I try to do an update to one row in a table containing two primary keys. Primary keys are `Trad_id` and `Trad_lang`. For each differen row I want to update with the correct data, but Eloquent updates all rows with the same `Trad_id`.

Why is Eloquent updating all rows?

```
$tradInt = \Model\Traduction::where('Trad_id', $reference->Trad_id)->where("Trad_lang", "INTERNE")->first();
$tradInt->Trad_text = 'ABC';
$tradInt->save();

$tradExt = \Model\Traduction::where('Trad_id', $reference->Trad_id)->where("Trad_lang", "EXTERNE")->first();
$tradExt->Trad_text = 123;
$tradExt->save();

+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Trad_id | Trad_lang | Trad_type | Trad_text |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|    1206 | INTERNE   |           | 123       |
|    1206 | EXTERNE   |           | 123       |
|    1206 | FR        |           | 123       |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: The `first()` method will only ever return one item so are you sure it's updating more than one row in the DB per update statement?  Try `dd()` the result of your query before updating so you can see what is being updated. Also, does your table require a composite primary key? Maybe that's what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that Laravel doesn't support composite keys and for sure they won't support it in future. So the solution is to use update query:

```
\Model\Traduction::where('Trad_id', $reference->Trad_id)
    ->where("Trad_lang", "EXTERNE")
    ->update(['Trad_text' => 123]);
```

Here is this issue:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

See the Taylor's response for that.